# Expected Value and Central limit Theorem

Tags: probability

The next two problems concern the drawing tickets at random with replacement from a box that contains six tickets
marked -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3.

What is the approximate probability that the sum of 100 draws is 0?

So I get the idea of using the normal probability distribution to estimate the probability. I got the SE to be 21.4 but then when I try to convert the Z score to actual probability I'm stuck:

Z=$\frac{(0-0)}{21.4}$ = 0

So the probability is 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by this argument, $50\%$ is the approximate probability that it is less than or equal to zero, not equal to zero. The probability that a normal is equal to zero is zero. Clearly, we want a better approximation than that (though it is indeed zero in the $n\to\infty$ limit). One crude way to do this is to realize that you know it is an integer. So you can instead compute the probability it will be between $-1$ and $1$ according to the normal distribution. Actually, it would be best to consider outcomes closer to $\pm 1$ than to zero to "round" to $\pm 1,$ so a better approximation would be to compute the probability it will be between $-1/2$ and $1/2.$ So to compute the probability that the standard Gaussian is between $-\frac{1}{2\times 21.4}$ and $\frac{1}{2\times 21.4}.$ (I haven't checked your computation of the $21.4$ but it seems in the right ballpark.)

Comment: WOW! I haven't even thought about this! following your method, will we be able to get an even more precise answer if we use -0.1 and 0.1 or as close to 0 as possible?

Comment: @pino231 No, you have missed the point. As you make that range smaller and smaller your probability will just go to zero. You want to choose choose the range so that the area of the curve is close to the area of the middle stack of boxes shown here (where the box width is 1). https://goo.gl/images/hwPeHL

Comment: ahhhh I see that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the random variable representing a ticket to be drawn. Its variance is:
$$V[T]=E[T^2]-E[T]^2=E[T^2]={9+4+1+1+4+9\over 6}={14\over3}$$
Let $S$ be the random variable representing the sum of 100 tickets to be drawn. Its variance is:
$$V[S]=100 V[T]=1400/3$$
and so the standard deviation is $$\sigma_s = \sqrt{V[S]} \approx 21.6$$

By the central limit theorem, $S$ will be approximately Gaussian distributed. For a Gaussian, $G$, with the same mean and standard deviation, the probability $P(-0.5<G<0.5)\approx 0.0185$. A simple Monte Carlo program confirms this value is close.

Is it obvious why this should work? I don't think so! We could modify the problem to have continuous random variables for the tickets:
$$X_i=T_i+U_i$$ where $T_i$ is as before and $U_i$ is uniform $[-0.5,0.5]$. Then the sum,
$$S' = \sum_i X_i=\sum T_i + \sum_i U_i$$ and
$$V[S']=100(14/3 + 1/12)$$
In this modified problem $S'$ is a continuous random variable, so it makes sense to integrate its pdf to evaluate probabilities. There is variance from $T_i$ and from $U_i$, but the former dominates. For situations where $\sum_i T_i=0$, there is the extra noise from $\sum_i U_i$ that spreads $S'$ outside the range[-0.5,0.5], but appproimately an equal number come into that range from the situations where $\sum_i T_i=1$ and $\sum_i T_i=-1$ to cancel out the effect. This is only the case because the variance for $\sum_i T_i$ is so large that the probability for it to take on the values $-1$, $0$, or $1$ are approximately the same. So it does work out for this particular problem, but it is not obvious without thinking about it carefully!

Comment: Don’t at all understand your point about why it’s not obvious (which is not to say I think it’s obvious). Of course adding some small additional noise changes the distribution somewhat. It doesn’t make sense to consider the probability your new variable lands exactly on zero since it’s continuous now. Also, why does it matter if the added noise takes some paths that would have landed on zero and moves them outside the range? Of course that happens but I don’t see the relevance to the quality of the approximation.

Comment: thank you for the clarification!